# A sidebar is overlapping over a panel element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a simple chat app and I want a sidebar where the user can select the rooms. The sidebar must be collapsible, but right know my sidebar is fixed and is overlapping the panel element where the chat conversations should display.

```css
.panel-body {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75%;
  float: rigth;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
          <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>



  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-body">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
                                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How I can fix this so that the panel element adjust the width base on if the sidebar is collapse or not?

Thank you i will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you (reply this answer if not) There are the same classes that bootstrap has, working from 1024px instead of bootstrap's native:

```
    /* Modify max-with to change breakpoint */
         @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
   .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
       position: static;
       float: none;
       width: auto;
       margin-top: 0;
       background-color: transparent;
       border: 0;
       -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: simply add this CSS styles **AFTER** Bootstrap's one. The correct order is: bootstrap css, jquery, bootstrap js, your own styles, then add this at the bottom of your styles.